# Use Generic Method With Type DataType

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion

This is ITest Interface:

```
public interface ITest
{
    Type ReturnType { get; }

    Object MyMethod(params object[] args);

}
```

And Test Class:

```
public class Test: ITest
{
    public Type ReturnType { get { return typeof(long); } }

    public Object MyMethod(params object[] args)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        foreach(object arg in args)
        {
          sum += (long)arg;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

So I need a method that convert automatically result of `ITest` Method with `ReturnType` Type.

I Think Something like This:

```
public T Transform<T>(Type T, object result)
{
   return (T)result;
}
```

And Use Like This:

```
Test test = new Test();
long result = Transform(test.ReturnType, test.MyMethod(1,2,3,4));
```

But as You Know I can't Use generic Method Like This, I **don't** want to declare return Type Explicitly like this:

```
long result = Transform<long>(test.MyMethod(1,2,3,4));
```

any suggestion?

Comment: Is reflection a option? Then it is possible

Comment: Then simply not possible(upto my knowledge)

Comment: Why don't you want to pass in a type parameter to the generic method?

Comment: Why `ITest` no generic?

Comment: @nawfal You'r right, that's a good option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly what you're asking is not possible without reflection.

You can mark ITest as `Generic` and henceforth everything becomes easy.

```
public interface ITest<T>
{
    Type ReturnType { get; }//redundatnt

    T MyMethod(params object[] args);
}


public class Test : ITest<long>
{
    public Type ReturnType { get { return typeof(long); } }//redundatnt

    public long MyMethod(params object[] args)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        foreach (object arg in args)
        {
            long arg1 = Convert.ToInt64(arg);
            sum += arg1;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}

Test test = new Test();
long result = test.MyMethod(1,2,3,4);//No transform nothing, everything is clear
```

Comment: I would say this approach defeats the purpose of the question

Comment: You could also not guarantee that `Convert.ToInt64` would work for the objects passed in as parameters.

Comment: @Moho You should know what method is doing and what you need to pass in

Answer (score 1):

Reflection is required, but the important thing is that this approach is highly questionable as well as not 100% possible as you cannot cast an `object` to a `long`.  Try running the below:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        int i = 1;
        object o = i;
        long l = (long)o;
    }
```

As Sriram demonstrated, it is possible to implement type specific methods, but I assume this would defeat the purpose of your question/design.  It would also be easier to simply have overloaded methods w/ different parameter types (i.e. int[], long[], etc), which has the benefit of ensuring that the cast will not throw an exception.

Comment: This definitely doesnt answers the question

Comment: @SriramSakthivel while you're right, I have seen members answer potential pitfalls in OP's approach as answers like this, even from reputed members.

Comment: I find that many times the true answer to a question on SO is not how to get something to work as the petitioner desires, but to help them understand why their approach is difficult (i.e. that it is incorrect).

Answer (score 1):

As @nawfal mentioned you could use ITest as Generic:

```
public interface ITest<T>
{

    T MyMethod(params object[] args);
}
```

Comment: That's what was answered 10 mins ago, with more detail.